# Order of placement of widgets in PyQt: Can I place a GraphicalLayoutWidget on a QHBoxLayout?

Tags: pyqt, pyqtgraph

I'm new to PyQt and pyqtgraph and have a heatplot, which I'd like to place on a widget (if that's the right term), adjacent to which a slider will eventually appear. The code I have thus far, which is a modification of something I've shamelessly copied from an online tutorial, is as follows:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtWidgets, mkQApp
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QHBoxLayout

from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore

pg.setConfigOption('background', 'lightgray')
pg.setConfigOption('foreground','black')

font = QtGui.QFont("Times", 18)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
   
        layout = QHBoxLayout()

        graph_widget = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget(show=True)
        self.setCentralWidget(graph_widget)
    
        self.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: heatmap display')
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: lightgray;")
        self.resize(1000,1000)

        #layout.addWidget(graph_widget) # Where my error occurs

        self.show()

        corrMatrix = np.array([
            [ 1.        ,  0.5184571 , -0.70188642],
            [ 0.5184571 ,  1.        , -0.86094096],
            [-0.70188642, -0.86094096,  1.        ]
        ])
        columns = ["A", "B", "C"]

        pg.setConfigOption('imageAxisOrder', 'row-major') 
    
        correlogram = pg.ImageItem()

        tr = QtGui.QTransform().translate(-0.5, -0.5) 
        correlogram.setTransform(tr)
        correlogram.setImage(corrMatrix)

        plotItem = graph_widget.addPlot() 
    
        plotItem.invertY(True)           
        plotItem.setDefaultPadding(0.0)  
        plotItem.addItem(correlogram)    
    
        plotItem.showAxes( True, showValues=(True, True, False, False), size=40 )

        ticks = [ (idx, label) for idx, label in enumerate( columns ) ]
        for side in ('left','top','right','bottom'):
            plotItem.getAxis(side).setTicks( (ticks, []) ) 
            plotItem.getAxis(side).setTickFont(font) 
        plotItem.getAxis('bottom').setHeight(10) 
           
        colorMap = pg.colormap.get("CET-D1")     
        bar = pg.ColorBarItem( interactive=False,values=(0,1), colorMap=colorMap)
        bar.setImageItem(correlogram, insert_in=plotItem)    

mkQApp("Correlation matrix display")
main_window = MainWindow()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.exec()
```

The result is shown below:

[image]

Eventually I would like to place the above in a layout, in which a row contains my plot, a slider (and a few other widgets). A TypeError message results when I un-comment the line `layout.addWidget(graph_widget)`. The message states

```
TypeError: addWidget(self, QWidget, stretch: int = 0, alignment: Union[Qt.Alignment, 
Qt.AlignmentFlag] = Qt.Alignment()): argument 1 has unexpected type 
'GraphicsLayoutWidget'
```

Is it not possible to place a `GraphicsLayoutWidget` on a `QHBoxLayout()`? If so, what's the correct way to organize things so I have my graph adjacent to which I can place sliders, line edits, etc.

Comment: You probably have different PyQt/PySide versions installed. Always import the Python binding for Qt first (or properly set up pyqtgraph before initialization). Also, be more consistent with your imports and avoid mixing namespaces, as it makes everything even more confusing. Just directly import from PyQt5 and eventually import pyqt *specific* classes after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue is that you are setting your `graph_widget` as the central widget for your `QMainWindow` instance and then later adding it to a layout with the intention of adding more widgets.

I think you are more likely to achieve the results you are looking for if you set a generic `QWidget` as the window's central widget, set a layout, and then add the `graph_widget` and any other widgets to the layout.

Here is an example using your code and the solution from @musicmante in the comments, and adding a vertical slider:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QHBoxLayout, QWidget, QSlider #  Import PyQt5 first before pyqtgraph
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtWidgets, mkQApp
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np

from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore

pg.setConfigOption('background', 'lightgray')
pg.setConfigOption('foreground','black')

font = QtGui.QFont("Times", 18)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.central = QWidget()                          # create a QWidget
        slider = QSlider(orientation=QtCore.Qt.Vertical)  # Vertical Slider

        graph_widget = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget(show=True)
        self.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: heatmap display')
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: lightgray;")
        self.resize(1000,1000)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.central)  # set the QWidget as centralWidget
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self.central)  # assign layout to central widget

        layout.addWidget(graph_widget) # No More error
        layout.addWidget(slider)       # add a slider

        self.show()

        corrMatrix = np.array([
            [ 1.        ,  0.5184571 , -0.70188642],
            [ 0.5184571 ,  1.        , -0.86094096],
            [-0.70188642, -0.86094096,  1.        ]
        ])
        columns = ["A", "B", "C"]

        pg.setConfigOption('imageAxisOrder', 'row-major')

        correlogram = pg.ImageItem()

        tr = QtGui.QTransform().translate(-0.5, -0.5)
        correlogram.setTransform(tr)
        correlogram.setImage(corrMatrix)

        plotItem = graph_widget.addPlot()

        plotItem.invertY(True)
        plotItem.setDefaultPadding(0.0)
        plotItem.addItem(correlogram)

        plotItem.showAxes( True, showValues=(True, True, False, False), size=40 )

        ticks = [ (idx, label) for idx, label in enumerate( columns ) ]
        for side in ('left','top','right','bottom'):
            plotItem.getAxis(side).setTicks( (ticks, []) )
            plotItem.getAxis(side).setTickFont(font)
        plotItem.getAxis('bottom').setHeight(10)

        colorMap = pg.colormap.get("CET-D1")
        bar = pg.ColorBarItem( interactive=False,values=(0,1), colorMap=colorMap)
        bar.setImageItem(correlogram, insert_in=plotItem)


mkQApp("Correlation matrix display")
main_window = MainWindow()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.exec()
```